# Emacs replaces spaces with tabs

Tags: emacs, tabs

The problem is that I want Emacs to save tabs when I entered them as tabs and spaces if I entered them as spaces. But the editor replaces my manually typed spaces with tab when the number of spaces reaches amonut that is defined in `tab-stop-list`, i.e. when I type

```
   →func1() {
   →   →some_long_command_name -param1 -param2 \
   →   →→→→→→→→→→→→→→→→→→→→→→→→-param3 -param4
```

(where tab is    `→` and space is `→` ) Emacs makes it

```
   →func1() {
   →   →some_long_command_name -param1 -param2 \
   →   →   →   →   →   →   →→→→-param3 -param4
```

Which breaks the indentation I wanted to preserve, if the length of the tab changes.

Comment: Emacs doesn't convert spaces to tabs like you describe.  Either you're using some funky extra package, or you're doing something else than what you describe (e.g. you re-indent the code, maybe?).

Comment: @Stefan now I think that may be ebuild-mode bug. Will try to contact with its developers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me as if you're after https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/SmartTabs ?

Comment: Yeah. For some reason I thought I’ve already installed it. But it wasn’t.

Comment: I will never work for the shell-mode, though ;_; https://github.com/jcsalomon/smarttabs/issues/11#issuecomment-10761636

Answer (score 3):

Customize option `indent-tabs-mode` to give the value `nil`. This stops Emacs from converting indentation whitespace to use `TAB` chars. `SPC` chars and `TAB` chars that you enter remain such.

Then you will need to either bind key `TAB` to `self-insert-command` or else use `C-q TAB` to insert a `TAB` character.  This means that you lose the `TAB` key as an indentation command.  Alternatively, you could bind some other key to a command that inserts a `TAB` char, or else bind some other key than `TAB` to the indentation command that `TAB` is bound to by default.

Comment: I wouldn’t want to lose auto indentation, I’d want to get rid only of what Emacs inserts after. I think auto indentation and replacing spaces shouldn’t be depending on each other. I could trace it to the `'indent-relative` function in `indent.el`, but I don’t know elisp to go deeper :D